# Palindrome program isn't comparing properly

Tags: c++, string, vector

I'm currently learning about vectors and trying to make a palindrome program using them. This is a simple program and so far, I'm trying to make it identify "I am what am I." as a palindrome properly. This is my program so far:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

vector <string> sentVec;

void getSent(string sent); 
void readBackwards(string sent); 

int main()
{
 string sent;

 getSent(sent);
 readBackwards(sent);
 return 0;
}

void getSent(string sent)
{
 cout << "Enter your sentence:" << endl;
 getline (cin,sent);

 string currentWord, currentLetter;

 for (int i = 0; i < sent.length(); i++) 
 {
  currentLetter = sent[i];

  if (currentLetter == " ") // inserts word
  {
   currentWord += sent[i];
   sentVec.push_back(currentWord);
   currentWord = "";
  }
  else if (currentLetter == ".") // inserts period
  {
   sentVec.push_back(currentWord);
   currentWord = sent[i];
   sentVec.push_back(currentWord);
  }
  else
  {
   currentWord += sent[i];
  }
 }
}

void readBackwards(string sent)
{
 string sentForwards, sentBackwards; 

 // create sentence forwards and backwards without the period.
 for (int i = 0; i < sentVec.size() - 1; i++)
 {
  sentForwards += sentVec[i];
 }

 for (int j = sentVec.size() - 2; j >= 0; j--)
 {
  sentBackwards += sentVec[j];

  if (j == sentVec.size() - 2)
   {
    sentBackwards += " ";
   }
 } 

 cout << "Sentence forwards is: " << sentForwards << endl;
 cout << "Sentence backwards is: " << sentBackwards << endl;

 if (sentForwards == sentBackwards)
 {
  cout << "This sentence reads the same backwards as forwards." << endl;
 }
 else 
 {
  cout << "This sentence does not read the same backwards as forwards." << endl;
 }
}
```

When I run this program, it prints:

```
Enter your sentence:
I am what am I.
Sentence forwards is: I am what am I
Sentence backwards is: I am what am I 
This sentence does not read the same backwards as forwards.
```

Why does this not trigger the if loop when comparing the two sentences?

Comment: Seriously, that looks like too much code to determine if a sentence reads the same backwards and forwards.  A simple 3 or 4 line function using `std::reverse()` is all you need.

Comment: Please see here for a much simpler implementation: http://ideone.com/rqJuOe

Comment: Add some logging to see what's going on. Log the length of both strings, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Because `sentBackwards` isn't the same as `sentForwards`, because `sentBackwards` has a trailing whitespace at the end, and thus they aren't the same.

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure how your program detects palindromes, but here is a simple iterative method:

```
#include <string>

bool isPalindrome(std::string in) {
    for (int i = 0; i < in.size() / 2; i++) {
        if (in[i] != in[in.size() - 1 - i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

It returns true if the string passed as an argument is a palindrome

Answer (score 1):

You should not only learn about `vector`, but also the STL algorithm functions such as [std::reverse](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse).

As the other answer given pointed out, one vector has a trailing whitespace.  You could have avoided all of that by simply taking the original vector, copying it to another vector, and calling `std::reverse`.  There is no need to write a loop:

```
void readBackwards()
{
   // copy the vector
   std::vector<std::string> sentBackwards = sentVec;

   // reverse it
   std::reverse(sentBackwards.begin(), sentBackwards.end());

   // see if they're equal
   if (sentVec == sentBackwards)
      cout << "This sentence reads the same backwards as forwards." << endl;
   else 
      cout << "This sentence does not read the same backwards as forwards." << endl;
}
```

This works, since `std::vector` has an overloaded `operator ==` that compares the items in each of the two vectors and returns `true` if all items are the same.

---

In addition to this, reading into a vector can be accomplished much more easily than what you attempted.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
//...
void getSent(string sent)
{
    // remove the periods(s)
    auto iter = std::remove_if(sent.begin(), sent.end(), [] (char ch) { return ch == '.';});
    sent.erase(iter, sent.end());

    // copy the data to a vector
    std::istringstream iss(sent);
    string currentword;
    while ( iss >> currentword)
        sentVec.push_back(currentword);
}
```

Note that we use the `std::istringstream` to serve as the space delimited parser, alleviating the need to write a loop looking for the space.  Also, the `std::remove_if` algorithm is used to remove any period characters from the string before we start to store the individual strings into a vector.

So basically, the only loop in this whole setup is the `while` to read from the stream into the vector.  Everything else is accomplished by using the algorithm functions, and taking advantage of the various member functions of `std::vector` (like the overloaded `==`)